# How to find the differences between two arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

I'm a new JavaScript user, but I've been tasked with creating a spreadsheet for my community and it seems I've run into a bump. I've been using Google Scripts along with Google Sheets (so my community can also see the information).

Basically I have two arrays, both populated with lists of players.

1. My first array is populated with a list of active players, these change every other day. Some people drop, some people get added, others stay on the list.
2. My second array is used to keep track of everyone, so it contains a list of all previous members.

My issue:
Suppose my second array contained the values "Player1","Player2", and "Player3", and my first array contains the values "Player1","Player2", and "Player3".

Now consider the change in the first array, perhaps Player1 is removed, and Player 4 is added (in random order), where the second array contains "Player1","Player2", and "Player3", but my first array contains the values "Player4","Player2", and "Player3". I want a something that compares the two arrays (in any order) and returns the difference between the first array and the second array, and then subsequently adds them onto the second array.

IE:
Array 1 -- Active Members = Player1,Player2,Player3,Player6,Player9,Player4
Array 2 -- Total Members = Player1,Player2,Player3,Player4,Player6,Player9

would return NO difference, but

Array 1 -- Active Members = Player1,Player4,Player3
Array 2 -- Total Members = Player2,Player3

would return Player1 and Player4, and then add them to Array 2 to make Array 2:
Player2,Player3,Player1,Player4

I know it's really confusing, but I can't wrap my head around how to get this to work!

Here's some pseudo code to demonstrate what I want:

```
if Array1[x] is found in Array2
ignore

but

if Array1[x] is not found in Array2
add the value of [x] to the end of Array2
```

I'm using Google Scripts to code for a Spreadsheet in Google Spreadsheet here's the basic outline of my code:

```
 for (var i=0;i<=range.length;i++){
 var playerName = sheetWAR.getRange(i+4,4).getValue(); // first 3 rows are for information
 }
```

where range is a value I insert view the Browser.inputBox command.

I then take this data and paste it to another sheet:

```
for (var j=0;j<=playerName.length;j++){
sheetRANK.getRange(j+2,3).setValue(playerName[j]);
}
```

Good, now I want to take those values and compare them with a list (that will default to empty!

```
var maxRow = sheetRANK.getLastRow();
for (var k=0; k<=maxRow; k++){
var activeRange = sheetRANK.getRange(k,1).getValue();
}
```

activeRange = Array2
playerNumber = Array1

I've tried both of the suggestions below and here's what happens:

```
If I have these values for each array:

activeRange = {"Viper", "Cobra", "Diamondback", "Python"}
and
playerName = {"Viper", "Cobra", "Anaconda", "Diamondback", "Python"}

resulting activeRange = {"Viper", "Cobra", "Diamondback", "Python", "", "", "Anaconda", "undefined"}

for both of the posted solutions.
```

I failed to realize that I had copied 1 above the playerName into the array, so a simple playerName.length-1 in the for loop solved that issue, the other issue was with a blank space appearing in the compiled list: this is probably the best demonstration of a new-to-JavaScript mistake. I simply forgot that I was using lastRow as the length, so if I had fewer values in  the activeRange (array2) than in playerNum (array1), it would copy down to the last row in array1, which would be a blank space in array2, then once it compiled those two arrays together, with array2 coming before array1, the blank space would separate the two.

Comment: What do you want the behavior to be when a user is not found in the first array but is found in the second array?

Comment: Please write some code to achieve what you want and then post a precise _error_ here.

Comment: If a user is not in the Active Members (Array 1), but is in the Total Members (Array 2), I want it to simply be ignored. Only if a member is present in Array 1, that is not present in Total Members should be acknowledged. I appreciate your response!

Comment: are the arrays simply arrays of strings? then it's simply `Array2.concat(Array1.filter(function(item) {
    return Array2.indexOf(item) < 0;
}));`

Comment: You don't know how happy I am to see a comment with something to try, but the issue is that I'm such a newbie at this, that I don't know how to use it currently... I hate to ask you to make it simpler than you already have, but please?

Comment: @JaromandaX I copy/pasted `Array2.concat(Array1.filter(function(item) { return Array2.indexOf(item) < 0; }));` that you posted, but all it seems to do is add the contents of Array1 to the end of Array2. I only want NEW entries in Array1 to be added to Array2.

Comment: No, it **RETURNS** what you want - I see, you want to change array2, my bad

Comment: @JaromandaX I swapped the Arrays around and it still returns the two arrays stacked onto one another, but this time with a space between it.

Comment: no spaces would happen with my code, so you've done something wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm really sorry if I'm confusing or irritating you, but I just recently started working with JS. When I use your script, it stacks Array1 onto Array 2. I should probably preface that with I made a new variable and stored the return in the variable ie: `var differences = YourCode'` and then displayed differences in the cells. It came up with the first Array, then the Second Array.

Comment: `the two arrays stacked onto one another` - so, duplicate entries?

Comment: your two arrays are arrays of **strings**, correct?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, they're both arrays of strings (both are arrays including player names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help:

```
var arr1 = ["Player1", "Player4", "Player3"];
var arr2 = ["Player2", "Player3"];

arr1.forEach(function(player) {
    if(arr2.indexOf(player) == -1) arr2.push(player);
});
console.log(arr2);

// ["Player2", "Player3", "Player1", "Player4"]
```

Comment: I tried this to no avail. I updated my main post with a bit more information. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: Just realized the "no avail" I spoke of was on my part. Your code worked perfectly, thanks a bunch! I would have never figured that out!